# Why AES can't Decrypt , PHP. Openssl

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm having problem with decrypting 
I have

```
 $key="Gwu078980";
 $cipher="aes-128-gcm";
 $iv=md5($cipher);
 $text="yaw0";
 $tag="";
 echo $encrypted=openssl_encrypt($text, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);

 echo $de_ciphertext=openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);
```

Output

```
ELRmWQ==
yaw0
```

So the *raw text* is `yaw0` and the *encrypted* is `ELRmWQ==` and the *decrypted* is `yaw0` so perfect.

But when I manually copy the encrypted text and use it as

```
$encrypted ="ELRmWQ==";
```

And I run the decryption
the decryption returns null.
Thanks in advance for anyone to help me out.

Comment: You misspelled `$encrypted` at the end. Is that in the real code or just a copying error?

Comment: Typing error...

Comment: What is `$de`? And you're missing the `$` before `ciphertext`. Why are you subtracting them?

Comment: Your `$tag` is probably an empty string without encrypting? `openssl_encrypt` modifies it by reference. It's required for your cipher (GCM and CCM).

Comment: @ccKep Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar it is $de_ciphertext not $de-cipher. I've edited it.

Comment: @ccKep I have even used a constant $tag as $tag="aan"; but experienced the same problem. Even after i declared it as $tag="aan;" , when I do var_dump of it, the contents still doesn't change, I don't know it $tag is a reserved variable in PHP 7.2? I further went ahead to change the variable to $a="aan"; but the problem is still the same.

Comment: You have to use the same value of `$tag` that `openssl_encrypt()` produces, just like  you use the same value of `$encrypted`.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

Your `openssl_encrypt` message modifies `$tag` by reference since you're using `aes-128-gcm`.

That parameter is required for `openssl_decrypt` aswell (when using AEAD - Authenticated Encryption and Decryption) and is probably an empty string in your case when you omit the `openssl_encrypt` call.

See [Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) in the docs:

The comment about storing `$cipher, $iv, and $tag` is the important part:

```
<?php
//$key should have been previously generated in a cryptographically safe way, like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't work. I was thinking maybe my column data type is not appropriate enough to store the iv. That is why I made it md5().

Comment: I have copied and pasted but it didn't work it works only when I run the decryption immediately after the encryption. But when I run the decryption later on the cipher text, I doesn't work. You should probably run it yourself to see if it works or not.

Comment: You need to **safe** what's in `$tag` after you encrypted a string using it... `openssl_encrypt` **sets** it - it doesn't matter if you assigned something to it beforehand.

Comment: Okay. I'll do so.